# Build Fail Sphinx Error contents.rst not found

Tags: read-the-docs

I follow the instructions on read the docs but I get this error:

> bash Sphinx error: master file
>   /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/mybinders/checkouts/latest/docs/source/contents.rst
>   not found

Do have to you the read the docs yaml file?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you have your own `conf.py` file, it overrides Read the Doc's default `conf.py`. By default, Sphinx expects the master doc to be `contents`. Read the Docs will set master doc to `index` instead (or whatever it is you have specified in your settings). Try adding this to your `conf.py`:

```
master_doc = 'index'
```

For more information, check out this issue: https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2569

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to have my `conf.py` because of the extensions I'm using so simply add

```
master_doc = 'contents'
```

to your `conf.py` and than

rename your `index.rst` to `contents.rst`.

Than after build passes OK you still won't see anything on ReadTheDocs, except "This page still doesn't exists" just go to:

```
https://your-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents.html
```

And you'll see your docs there.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem through the readthedocs tutorial this week. I solved the issue by changing the location of `index.rst` from `projectname/docs/source` to `docs` since that was the error that appeared in the build log. After this Readthedocs was able to build without problems.

Hope it helps someone.