# Build error index.rst not found in ReadtheDocs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I get this when I try to update my docs:

> sphinx.errors.SphinxError: master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/redditeasy/checkouts/latest/index.rst not found

It didn't used to show up like that. I looked at [Build Fail Sphinx Error contents.rst not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336234/build-fail-sphinx-error-contents-rst-not-found) but it didn't help either. How can I solve this?

Comment: From your [Builds page](https://readthedocs.org/projects/redditeasy/builds/) I see that [`six` is not installed](https://readthedocs.org/projects/redditeasy/builds/12447051/) but is required. Even though it is in your `docs/requirements.txt`, you need to [configure RTD to install requirements](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-documentation-requires-additional-dependencies) from this file.

Comment: My previous comment was half-right. There is a [bug in RTD](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/7705) where `six` was removed from Sphinx 3.0.0 and RTD had set that version to the default. A fix is imminent. Meanwhile my suggestion is a temporary workaround.